# Animate / turn lights on and off in a specific order using geometry nodes

Tags: animation, shaders, shader-nodes, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to Animate / turn lights on and off in a specific order using geometry nodes.  The numbers are the order I wish them to turn on/off.  So when 1 is turned on all others are off, when 2 is turned on all others are off, etc...  Can geometry nodes do this?

[image: img1]

[image: iimg2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An individual assignment of materials is only possible if they are no longer instances (==copies of a single object), but a freely processable mesh.

For this you have to use the node `Realize Instances`. But first you would have to capture the index of the instance with `Capture Attribute` to be able to work with it further:

[image]

However, there are also situations where the objects should remain as instances. For this the following solution would fit, where you simply build a kind of switch at instantiation, where you decide which points should instantiate which objects:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

*PS:* I don't know how you want to control the lights, but you could solve the animation for example with the help of the node `Scene Time`. Maybe the math node `Snap` will help you further on.